# ORACLE PL/SQL Conditional SPOOL (not empty)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there a way in which I don't SPOOL a file based on a criteria? The following code will SPOOL an empty file, which is not useful.

```
VARIABLE :SPOOLYN AS VARCHAR2(1);
DECLARE
    VARSPOOL CHAR ( 1 ) := '&SpoolYN';
BEGIN
    :SPOOLYN := VARSPOOL;
END;

** Some sort of IF condition based on variable :SPOOLYN **
SPOOL "File.txt";
 -- Including all Data to be SPOOLed and SPOOL OFF;

** End of IF condition **
```

Comment: Somehow it didn't went through completely. I'm trying to update it.

Comment: Done. For a reason it didn't allow me to save "(1)". I had to change to "( 1 )".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `SPOOL` is a SQLPlus command, this would be a SQLPlus question, not PL/SQL. Generally it's no big deal, folks just process nothing since most shell scripts are line-based and so no lines does no work. Or they delete the file, or simply skip doing anything further in their shell script.

SQLPlus has no conditional logic of its own. However, it does allow for dynamic replacement and that can be used as a conditional workaround:

**spool_data.sql:**

```
spool file.txt
select ...
spool off
```

**donothing.sql:**
[empty - it's just to avoid getting an error message if you say N]

**primary script:**

```
VARIABLE SPOOLYN VARCHAR2(1);

DECLARE
    VARSPOOL CHAR ( 1 ) := '&SpoolYN';
BEGIN
    :SPOOLYN := VARSPOOL;
END;
/

column x new_value spoolme

select DECODE(:spoolyn,'Y','spool_data','donothing') x from dual;

@&&spoolme

exit
```

Supply `Y` at the prompt and it invokes the `spool_data.sql` script which spools `file.txt`. Supply `N` and it invokes the empty `donothing.sql` script and does nothing. But such an awkward workaround is probably not worth it. An empty file is easier to work with in my opinion. We should just accept that SQLPlus is a command line interface and not a programming language and keep our conditional logic either in PL/SQL or in shell.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to adjust this approach to my requirement. As I could not create multiple scripts because I need to pass variables accross them, I opted to create an empty-only directory & use the DECODE concept to determine the correct Spool location. Like that, I can ensure there are no empty files to the main directory.